# Is it mandatory to fill security questions and answers in order to download apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I was trying to download and install a new app, when a badge appeared on the screen. Apparently I have to choose three security question (and the corresponding answers) to improve the security of my Apple-ID. I clicked on "Not now" but in this way I can't install the app.

**It is mandatory to write questions and answers? Is there any way to skip the procedure and download the apps?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is a change in account status, it blocks all subsequent Apple ID authentication from completing successfully until you resolve the issue. I've seen this happen with:

- Security Questions / Answers when this rolled out a few months back.
- Credit Card / Billing issues.
- Purchases from a device previously unused by your account.

Only after resolving the particular issue will you be allowed to continue.